# Renumber the integers inside a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to renumber the integers inside a string, that has this format (letters and int numbers): "e1b2xx4d3".

In this example, I want to get: "e1b2xx3d4";

I have written the following JS code:

```
var count = 0;
var matches;
var transcript = "e1b2xx4d3";
var transcript1 = transcript;
regex = /\d+/g;
while ((matches = regex.exec(transcript)) !== null) {
    transcript1 = transcript1.replace(matches[0], ++count);
}
console.log(transcript1);
```

The idea is to replace each number in the string by its sequence number (count), but it does not work because of destructive replaces (here, we get "e1b2xx4d3", because "xx4" is replaced with "xx3", but at the next iteration by "xx4" back).

I need to do this with regex because the case that I deal with is more complex than the one shown and requires using regex.

I think that I have to do it in two passes (iterations): 1. compiling replacements and 2. applying replacements simultaneously.

By curiousity, can someone find a way to do this in one pass ?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0frru6fr/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is usually done with a replacing function:

```js
n = 0
result = "e1b2xx4d3".replace(/\d+/g, function() { return ++n })
alert(result)
```

See [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) for more info.